# Does the converse of the Picard–Lindelöf Theorem (Existence and Uniqueness Theorem) hold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The Theorem:

[image]

Does the converse of the theorem hold true? If there exists a unique solution in the interval, the could we say that f and it's partial derivative with respect to x are continuous on that interval?

If not, what would a counter example look like?

Comment: No, take $f(x) = |x|$, $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: It is enough to assume that the function is locally lipschitz (no need to involve derivatives).